# volume under the Gaussian function?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, error-function

I'm trying to calculate the volume between the unit disk and the two variable analog of the Gaussian function. This is how I'm trying to calculate it:
$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}e^{-x^2-y^2} dy\space dx$$
Which I've simplified into the following.
$$\int_{-1}^1e^{-x^2}(\sqrt\pi erf(\sqrt{1-x^2})-\sqrt\pi erf(-\sqrt{1-x^2}))\space dx$$
Which in turn, due to the fact that $erf(x)$ is an odd function becomes:
$$2\sqrt\pi\int_{-1}^1e^{-x^2}erf(\sqrt{1-x^2})\space dx$$
But after this I don't know what to do. I've tried asking [this](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) and [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) site but neither of them give anything but an estimation. Am I missing something? Did I mess up somewhere? Or is the answer not possible in terms of elementry functions?

Comment: Well, I don't know what to do from here. But Mathematica doesn't either so it really does seem like a difficult problem. On a side note, the numerical answer is about 1.9859, and a quick google search doesn't reveal anything obvious.

Comment: A couple of technicalities: (1) You're integrating over a _disk,_ not just a circle. (2) Whether you have a three-dimensional function here is (at best) ambiguous. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918740).) [Elsewhere,](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianFunction.html) your function is described as two-dimensional, although you can make a three-dimensional _graph_ of it. A better description would simply be "two-variable Gaussian."

Comment: @NickGuerrero I tried Wolfram Alpha and was a bit disappointed that it did not give an exact result for the original form of the integral, since the transformation to polar coordinates is a well-known technique for the two-variable Gaussian and since WA easily solved it in that form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your integral be $I$.  Expressed in polar coordinates, $$I=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 e^{-r^2} \,r\,dr\,d\theta.$$
You should be able to take it from there.

Or, look up the [chi squared distribution](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.0327.pdf), and make a change of variables to bring your $e^{-x^2}$ into the form that article expects, $e^{-x^2/2}$.